# Get value of only that style attribute who have font family

Tags: javascript

Html Code:

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:13px;">Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:13px;">50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:13px;">Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:13px; color:#666; font-weight:bold; 
  text-decoration:none;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left;white-space:nowrap;">94</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript Code:

```
<script>

  var tg_name = document.getElementsByTagName("td"); 
  var l_tgname = tg_name.length;    
  array_get = [];

  for(h=0;h<=l_tgname;h++){ 

    var val_gt_chck = document.getElementsByTagName("td")[h].hasAttribute("style");  

    if(val_gt_chck){

        var val_gt = document.getElementsByTagName("td")[h].getAttribute("style");  
        if(val_gt!==null && val_gt !== ''){     

            check_words = val_gt.includes('font-family');

            if(check_words){
                alert(val_gt);
                array_get.push(val_gt);
            }               
        }
    }                   
  } 

 alert(array_get);
</script>
```

I wanted to combine all the data in one variable and access that variable outside the loop.It give the error  that "Cannot read property 'has Attribute' of undefined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was wrong for condition and includes replaced by indexOf for better compatibility:

```js
  var tg_name = document.getElementsByTagName("td"); 
  var l_tgname = tg_name.length;    
  array_get = [];
  for(h=0;h<l_tgname;h++){     
    var val_gt_chck = document.getElementsByTagName("td")[h].hasAttribute("style"); 
    if(val_gt_chck){    
        var val_gt = document.getElementsByTagName("td")[h].getAttribute("style");  
        if(val_gt!==null && val_gt !== ''){                 
            check_words = val_gt.indexOf('font-family:') > -1;
            if(check_words){    
                console.log(val_gt);
                array_get.push(val_gt);


            }               
        }
    }                   
  }        
console.log(array_get);
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
 <th>Firstname</th>
 <th>Lastname</th>
 <th>Age</th>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:13px;">Jill</td>
 <td>Smith</td>
 <td style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:13px;">50</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:13px;">Eve</td>
  <td>Jackson</td>
  <td style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:13px; color:#666; font-weight:bold; 
  text-decoration:none;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:left;white-space:nowrap;">94</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yeah I got it after posting that for loop is creating an issue..Thanks